# Start two separate y-axis from same location in high-chart

Tags: highcharts

I have two data ranges, one contains percentage and other contains total values. Percentage can't be negative and but the total value can be negative.
The issue is that I want the y-axis to be in sync.

http://jsfiddle.net/79cg2u04/

As in above fiddle, percentage bar is starting from the base i.e. 0% is at the bottom. Whereas, for `total` -400k is at the bottom of the chart. I want the 0 of `percent` and `total` to be in sync. If the 0 of `total` is in the middle (two ticks above the baseline) then 0 of `percent` should also move 2 ticks above the baseline.

Comment: Please fix your link to be a link, not a code block. Try to provide a [Minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question, not just in a jsfiddle.

Comment: See the topic and answers here https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2554384-multiple-axis-alignment-control With the code from the fiddle posted in the linked website I guess you can achieve what you want